# matlab plot vectors must be the same lengths

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am writing a program regarding solving the following boundary value problem using **shooting-bisection method**:

```
y''-y+x=0, y(0)=y(1)=0.
```

I first convert this to a system of first order equations, set

```
y'=z
```

then I let dydt represent the vector (y',z'), and come up with the script file:

```
function dydt=shoot(t,y)
dydt=[y(2);y(1)-t]
end
```

With this, I then came up with the following code:

```
clear
clc
a=0;
b=1;
alpha=0;
beta=0;
s(1)=(beta-alpha)/(b-a);
s(2)=-1
[G,Y]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(1)]);
[G,Z]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(2)])
hold
tol=1e-4
u=s(1);
v=s(2);
while abs(u-v)>tol;
s(3)=(u+v)/2;
[G,W]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(3)]);
if W(end,1)>0
    u=s(3);
else
    v=s(3);
end
end

 [G,W]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(3)])

plot(G,Y(:,1),'-o', G,Z(:,1),'-o',G,W(:,1),'-o')
```

Then I run the program, MATLAB said I'm using the plot argument incorrectly, where plot vectors must be the same lengths. I have no idea how to fix this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the size of `G` and what is the size of `Y(:,1)`? They need to be the same size.

Comment: Your iteration would terminate in one step if you were to use the secant method (or the regula falsi method for a bracketed variant). The problem is linear, thus the second boundary value depends linearly on the first one, and that linear function can be determined by two points.

Comment: @LutzL I think I am using the bisection method after two shootings. Do you mean my loop terminates after one step in this case?

Comment: If you solve `0=f(x)=3x-1` using bisection starting with `[0,1]`, you will iterate infinitely (until you hit the stopping criterion), as the exact solution is an infinite binary fraction. With the secant method you find the solution in one step. This situation is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Y`, `Z` and `W` outputs are from different runs of `ode113`. The output independents variables, `G` from each run are different because `ode113` is an adaptive solver. There are two ways you can fix this. You can save your `G` outputs as separate variables:

```
...
[Gy,Y]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(1)]);
[Gz,Z]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(2)]);
...
[Gw,W]=ode113('shoot',[a b],[alpha;s(3)]);
plot(Gy,Y(:,1),'-o', Gz,Z(:,1),'-o',Gw,W(:,1),'-o');
```

Or you could specify a fixed set of output points [by specifying more than two points for `tspan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode113.html#inputarg_tspan) (second argument to `ode113`):

```
...
tspan = linspace(a,b,50);
[G,Y]=ode113('shoot',tspan,[alpha;s(1)]);
[G,Z]=ode113('shoot',tspan,[alpha;s(2)]);
...
[G,W]=ode113('shoot',tspan,[alpha;s(3)]);
plot(G,Y(:,1),'-o', G,Z(:,1),'-o',G,W(:,1),'-o');
```

Unless your version of Matlab is more than 10 years old, you should also specify your integration function, `shoot`, via a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html), not a string, i.e.:

```
[Gw,W]=ode113(@shoot,[a b],[alpha;s(3)]);
```